# Converion of pdf page to fixed size images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I want to convert pdf pages to images of same size(aspect ratio maintained) irrespective of the pdf quality. Say A4 size. I am using convert from Imagemagick for this but struggling to get the fixed size of images for different pdfs of different quality.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get the time to check this!

Comment: Will notify you once I check this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
convert -density 288 document.pdf -resize 2480x3508 result.png
```

The density must come before the `PDF` to ensure the rasterisation is done at sufficient quality/resolution.

If you want that centred on a piece of A4 and padded with white to fill the page:

```
convert -density 288 document.pdf -resize 2480x3508 -background white -gravity center -extent 2480x3508 result.png
```